# how add vertical column to vertical column

Tags: rectangle, column

I have column of text like this:

```
Abba
Foo
Boo
M
```

and I want to transform it to:

```
Abba = Abba
Foo = Foo
Boo = Boo
M = M
```

I can add " = " to end column of text via `C-x space` and `M-x string-insert-rectangle`, also
I can copy column via vertical selection `C-x space`,
but how I paste column to the right of another column?

Comment: With Magnar's `multiple-cursors` library you can place a cursor at the beginning all lines in a selected region; then you can hold down the shift key and the alt key and move the arrow once to the right (which will select the word on each line; then you can hit the copy command (which should also deselect the region, if not then press C-g one time); then hit the space bar, type an = sign, then hit the space bar, and yank/paste.  At this point you are done, and just hit the enter key to exit.

Comment: The easiest way to do this with vanilla Emacs would be to use a macro.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really want to use rectangles for this, because the desired end result is not aligned as rectangles.

Either use a keyboard macro. e.g.:

- <kbd><f3></kbd> - start recording
- <kbd>C-k</kbd><kbd>C-y</kbd><kbd>SPC</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>SPC</kbd><kbd>C-y</kbd> - transform the first line
- <kbd><right></kbd><kbd><f4></kbd> - move to the next line, and stop recording
- <kbd><f4></kbd><kbd><f4></kbd><kbd><f4></kbd> - replay for the remaining lines

Or `query-replace-regexp`:

<kbd>C-M-%</kbd> `.*` <kbd>RET</kbd> `\& = \&` <kbd>RET</kbd>